# Remote MySQL : I Can Read Database Tables Names, But Can't Read The Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I just create a Remote MySQL access from my other database server (remote) and I can see tables in it :

```
// SHOW ALL TABLES NAME
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]} <br>" ;
}
```

I can also see what columns name on each tables by using this :

```
// SHOW COLUMNS NAME OF A TABLE
$sql = 'DESCRIBE wp_ps_product_sku';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Column: {$row[0]} <br>" ;
}
```

but why I can't see any rows inside each table?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * wp_ps_product_sku';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
print_r($result);
```

it always gives me an empty result. for any tables. same result. it's always empty. what did I missed here? is it possible that server just give me an access to read the database structure only, but not the data?

thank you.

Comment: You need to fetch the results to see the rows.

Comment: you need to use the fetch function for you third example.. if you can see the table structure then at least you have SELECT privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your select statement, you are missing the 'from' clause.

```
select * from wp_ps_product_sku;
```